# What is the Java 8 way to pull an object from a set?

Tags: java-8, closures

I'd like to pull an item out of a set, and keep it, based on a predicate.  It sure seems like this should be possible, but I can't find a way to prevent going thru the list twice.  Such an operation could be used to 'pop' an object based on a dynamic priority.

Perhaps I should stick with an iterator.

Here's an example:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class RemoveAndUse {

    class A {
        int x;
        A(int x) { this.x = x;}
    }

    class B {
        int y;
        B(int y) { this.y = y;}
    }

    @Test
    public void removeHappyPath() {
        Set<A> aList = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new A(1), new A(2), new A(3)));
        B b = new B(2);

        // remove and keep an A that matches b
        A found = aList.stream()
                .filter( a -> a.x == b.y )
                .findAny().get();

        aList.removeIf( a -> a.x == b.y);
        // or: aList.remove(found);

        assert(!aList.contains(found));
        assert(found.x == b.y);

    }
}
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: If you have a proper hashcode/equals implementation, remove takes constant time with an `HashSet`, so calling `aList.remove(found)` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
A found;
for (Iterator<A> it = aList.iterator();it.hasNext();) {
  A a = it.next();
  if (a.x == b.y) {
    found = a;
    it.remove();
    break;
  }
}
```

O(n) is guaranteed;

Comment: Also you should check if such element exists at all. Maybe set A does not contain any B.

Comment: Yes, an iterator works.  However, I was wondering if there was a solution using lambda features.  Then I can create a generic 'pop'